# PSake extensions?

Tags: powershell, scripting, build-automation, psake

I recently discovered Powershell and through that [PSake](http://code.google.com/p/psake/). If you are using it and you've extended it or created tasks for it, please share!

Comment: The project doesn't appear to have any downloads.

Comment: Looks like they might not be "ready for release", but there's code and examples under the source tab.

Comment: BTW...I don't mean anything about the code quality by not ready for release.  Just that they aren't packaging it that way yet.

Comment: The whole "build system" is the small powershell script "psake.ps1" in  the root... works fine, just needs extension functions to make it nicer.

Comment: This seems too open for Stack Overflow: it's not really a question.

If you keep it, please mark as Community Wiki.

Answer (score 1):

JP Boodhoo has [evidently extended psake](http://blog.developwithpassion.com/2008/10/30/interested-in-trading-in-your-nant-builds-a-teaser/). Just hoping he would release what he's made...

Answer (score 1):

If still interested in psake, there is new project [psake-contrib](http://github.com/JamesKovacs/psake-contrib). Still empty, but I hope not for long time :)